# Liveness probe failure output not in kubelet logs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

The output from a liveness probe failure when using `exec` does not show up in the kubelet event logs (kubernetes version 1.3.2).

For example, I created a pod from the liveness probe example here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/liveness/

Using exec-liveness.yaml, I do not get any output from why the `Liveness probe failed:`

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                            SubobjectPath           TypeReason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                            -------------           --------    ------      -------
  1m        1m      1   {default-scheduler }                                    Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned liveness-exec to my-node
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet my-node}   spec.containers{liveness}   Normal      Pulling     pulling image "gcr.io/google_containers/busybox"
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet my-node}   spec.containers{liveness}   Normal      Pulled      Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/google_containers/busybox"
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet my-node}   spec.containers{liveness}   Normal      Created     Created container with docker id e84949417706
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet my-node}   spec.containers{liveness}   Normal      Started     Started container with docker id e84949417706
  44s       24s     3   {kubelet my-node}   spec.containers{liveness}   Warning     Unhealthy   Liveness probe failed:
```

Comment: What environment are you running on? Can you search the kubelet.log (at `/var/log/kubelet.log` or `journalctl -u kubelet`) for `Liveness probe for "`? This doesn't reproduce for me.

Comment: We are running our cluster on GKE.  I get the same result in the kubelet.log


`I0830 16:47:18.398339    3665 prober.go:106] Liveness probe for "liveness-exec_namespace(uid):liveness" failed (failure): 
`

Comment: Ah, it does reproduce for me on GKE. This is a bug, I filed an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/31717).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed in Kubernetes v1.4, by https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/30731.